# Why my procedure insert just first character from string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Why my procedure insert just first character from string?
I have dat query:

```
USE [TCO_Orders_SS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertIroBOMParts]    Script Date: 07/15/2016 08:28:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertIroBOMParts]
@OrderID int,
@OrderSelection int,
@Idx varchar,
@Component varchar,
@DrawingNo varchar,
@PartNo varchar,
@BatchNoParts varchar,
@Amount varchar,
@Comments varchar

AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO  Orders_IroBOMParts(OrderID,OrderSelection, idx,componenent,drawingno,partno,batchno,amount,comments)

      VALUES (@OrderID,@OrderSelection, @Idx,@Component,@DrawingNo,@PartNo,@BatchNoParts,@Amount,@Comments)
END
```

I try to insert into for more line but insert just first caracter from my string, if i have String "Modern" put into table just "M". BUT WHY?

[image]

My code for insertion in vb.net are:

```
For Each gvr As TableRow In TabelVerificari.Rows

            For i = 1 To TabelVerificari.Rows.Count - 1

                Idx = "P" & i
                Dim Result1 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_Component" & "_" & Col & i)
                Dim Result2 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_Drowing" & "_" & Col & i)
                Dim Result3 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_PartNo" & "_" & Col & i)
                Dim Result4 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_BatchNo" & "_" & Col & i)
                Dim Result5 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_Amount" & "_" & Col & i)
                Dim Result6 As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("BOX_Comments" & "_" & Col & i)

                Component = Result1.Text
                Drawing = Result2.Text
                PartNo = Result3.Text
                batchNo = Result4.Text
                Amount = Result5.Text
                Comments = Result6.Text

                Dim InsertBOM As SqlConnection = Nothing
                InsertBOM = FunctionConnection()
                Dim cmdBOM As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

                Try
                    'Insert Function 
                    cmdBOM.Connection = InsertBOM
                    cmdBOM.CommandTimeout = 50
                    cmdBOM.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmdBOM.CommandText = "InsertIroBOMParts"

                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderSelection", i)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Idx", Idx)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Component", Component)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrawingNo", Drawing)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNo", PartNo)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNoParts", batchNo)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", Amount)
                    cmdBOM.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments)

                    InsertBOM.Open()
                    cmdBOM.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    LBL_Error.Text = "Please complete correctly boxes!"
                    Exit Sub
                Finally

                    If InsertBOM.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        InsertBOM.Close()
                    End If
                    'Session("OrderNo") = OrderID
                    'Response.Redirect("MV_UpdateSample.aspx")
                End Try

            Next
            Exit For
        Next
```

Comment: [varchar ( n | max )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176089.aspx) When *n* is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the *width* of your `VARCHAR` variables.  Currently you have:

```
@Idx varchar,
@Component varchar,
@DrawingNo varchar,
@PartNo varchar,
@BatchNoParts varchar,
@Amount varchar,
@Comments varchar
```

This specifies no numerical width, which defaults to a width of one character.  Instead, specify a width in number of characters which you expect to reasonably fit all your data, e.g.:

```
@Idx varchar(55),
@Component varchar(55),
@DrawingNo varchar(55),
@PartNo varchar(55),
@BatchNoParts varchar(55),
@Amount varchar(55),
@Comments varchar(55)
```

This would give each `VARCHAR` a width of 55 characters.